# How do I stop useDispatch() from dispatching an action infinitely?

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

**Background**

I am working in a project with React-Redux and React Hooks.

I have a component that dispatches an action `fetchCollectionData()`, which first dispatches an action `requestCollectionData()`,which updates the reducer's waiting attribute to true. Then `fetchCollectionData()` makes a superagent request to get data from the server. Once the response comes back, `fetchCollectionData()` dispatches another action `receiveCollectionData()`, which updates the reducer with the result and sets the waiting attribute to false. The API result brings back data which gets passed down to a table in a child component.

**Problem:** useDispatch() dispatches the `fetchCollectionData()` action in an infinite loop. I only want this action to be dispatched once, when the component mounts.

**Attempt**: I've tried using the useEffect() hook `useEffect(fetchCollectionData(), [])`, but I get an error stating that useEffect shouldn't be used for promises.

**Error Text:**

```
Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

    in ContainerComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:35)
    in Switch (at App.js:33)
    in div (at App.js:20)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:19)
    in App (at Root.js:8)
    in Provider (at Root.js:7)
    in Root (at src/index.js:8)
```

I tried changing the action to `export async function fetchCollectionData()`, but that led me to more errors.

**Parent Component**

```
export const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData());
  const data = useSelector(state => state.accountMaintenanceReducer.result);
  const rows = data ? data : [];
  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div className="section-header">
        <span>Account Maintenance</span>
      </div>
      <TableComponent rows={rows} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { Table, TableHead, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell } from '@material-ui/core';

const columns = [,
  {name: 'Primary Owner', key: 'owner'},
  {name: 'Mailing Address', key: 'address'},
];

const dataToRows = (data) => {
  if (data.rows.length) {
    return data.rows.map(row => {
      const index = row.ownerAndAddress.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(13));
      const owner = row.ownerAndAddress.substring(0, index);
      const address = row.ownerAndAddress.substring(index + 2);
      return {
        owner: owner,
        address: address,
      }
    });
  }
};

export const TableComponent = (data) => {
  const rows = dataToRows(data);
  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          {columns.map(column => (
            <TableCell key={columns.indexOf(column)}>
              {column.name}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        { rows ?
          rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={rows.indexOf(row)}>
              { Object.keys(row).map(cell => (
                <TableCell className={cell} key={cell}>
                  {row[cell]}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          )) :
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>No Data</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        }
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

**actions**

```
export function receiveCollectionData(body) {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_COLLECTION_DATA',
    result: body,
  }
}

export function requestCollectionData() {
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_COLLECTION_DATA',
  }
}

export function fetchCollectionData() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestCollectionData());
    return request.get(`api/Accounts/GetCollectionBySearch?searchString=Smith`)
      .then(res => res.body)
      .then(body=> dispatch(receiveCollectionData(body)))
  }
}
```

**reducer**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_COLLECTION_DATA':
      return {
        ...state,
        waiting: true
      };
    case 'RECEIVE_COLLECTION_DATA':
      return {
        ...state,
        result: action.result,
        waiting: false
      };
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

**Desired Solution**:

What I'd like to do is mimic the functionality of `componentDidMount()`, and dispatch `fetchCollectionData()` once the component mounts. It seems that `fetchCollectionData()` dispatches again as soon as `receiveCollectionData()` resolves, causing an infinite loop.

**Disclaimer**:

The goal is to get a solution that utilizes React Hooks with Redux and does not rely on Class Components.

Answer (score 0):

at Parent component

---

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(()=> dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData(), []);
```

---

should work. 
for some reason it seems that when you tried useEffect it was without dispatch

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.
When I use `const dispatch = useDispatch(); useEffect(() => dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData()));` I get the error text that I listed above.

Comment: what about add { , [] } in the end of the effect? (edit my answer..)

Comment: Both  `useEffect(() => dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData()));` and `useEffect(() => dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData()), []);` produce the same error text.

Comment: can you add catch() method to fetchCollectionData() and console the error there ? because my guess the problem isnt in react or the way you call the action, it inside the action

Comment: .catch(err => console.log(err)); is not producing any errors on the action.

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

`const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(()=> dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData(), []);`

To:

`const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(()=> {dispatch(actions.fetchCollectionData()}, []);`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that the above didnot solve it one simple if statement inside the useEffect solves it. In my case I had a value that was initially null, so I wanted to mimic the good, old ComponentDidMount method. Here is the straightforward solution.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (yourvalue === null) 
           dispatch(actiontodispatch()); 
        }, []);
```

Here the crucial part is the value which is at the beginning null/ false or any other. Not sure on performance implications, though.